# How to convert Arabic text to speech in an Android app?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, arabic

How to convert arabic text to speech in an Android application while the current Android TTS does not support the Arabic language?

Please, I want my app to read arabic text.

Comment: Do you have any demo of the same? Even I want to do a TTS for Arabic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with **al-mintiq** which is based on **espeak**. It is tested on Android. Though, it is still in its 0.2 release. Here is [the release notes](https://tahadz.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/mintiq0/).

You can also try **NVDA**, here is the link to [arabic NVDA](http://arabic-nvda.org/).

Comment: The second link for NVDA is no longer working