# Arabic Text to Speech on Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, arabic-support

How to achieve Text to Speech in Arabic for Android in Native Android TTS? Is there option available for Arabic? There is an option for Arabic in Speech to Text. Similarly is there an Option for TTS?
I researched for links in stackoverflow and other sites. But few say there are SDKs like Acapela and Sestek which support Arabic in Android. 
But isnt there a way to speak in Arabic in Android Native TTS?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29071836/2016500

Comment: Ok will try the libraries. Doesnt the Native Android TTS support Arabic?